# Spring Data Gemfire configuration issues

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

I am following the Spring Data Gemfire sample configuration on my application as below:

```
<gfe:cache/>   
<gfe:local-region id="Customer">
    <gfe:cache-listener>
        <bean class="com.my.app.util.LoggingCacheListener"/>
    </gfe:cache-listener>
</gfe:local-region>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.GemfireCacheManager">
    <property name="regions">
        <set>
            <ref bean="Customer"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And got the issue as :
aused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.CacheParser.parsePdxDiskStore(CacheParser.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.CacheParser.doParse(CacheParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.GemfireNamespaceHandler.parse(GemfireNamespaceHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely the reason for this Exception is you are using an incompatible version of the core Spring Framework (e.g. earlier than 3.2.1) with Spring Data GemFire.

What version of Spring Data GemFire and the core Spring Framework are you using?

Spring Data GemFire as of 1.3.0 was already using the core Spring Framework 3.2.2.RELEASE.

If you are using the core Spring Framework 3.2.x line in your application, then I encourage you to use the latest, most stable version of the 3.2.x line, 3.2.9.RELEASE.

Spring Data GemFire 1.3.3 and later definitely requires core Spring Framework 3.2.1 or above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.1.4.